# twisted.mail error using Scrapy 1.0.4

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I'm really new with the Scrapy framework, so I was trying to complete the tutorial provided in the documentation:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project

The problem is that when I run the code, i get the following error:

```
from twisted.mail.smtp import ESMTPSenderFactory
ImportError: No module named 'twisted.mail'
```

I am using Python 3.5.1 and I have intalled both Scrapy 1.0.4 and Twisted 15.5.0. But the problem is that I cannot find any mail module in the twisted installation directory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy does not support Python 3.5.1.  [As explained in the documentation, use Python 2.7.11.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)